# Guardar contraseña en un archivo python (.py) para utilizarla en la coneccion a la base de datos

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, django

Estoy utilizando 2 base de datos una en postgres y la otra en sql 2008, la base de datos que esta en sql el usuario es el que conecta introduciendo el  ip servidor, ususario y passw, lo que si esta correcta la guarda en un archivo .py para que cuando se apague y encienda el servidor ya se mantenga conectado al sql, en estos momentos se guarda en texto plano y no puedo seguirlo haciendo.
settings.py

```
try:
     DATABASES['prueba'] = leerArchivo()['prueba']
  except Exception:
pass
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['src.apps.System.routers.SystemRouter']
```

Donde leerArchivo esta aquí

```
import os
path_to_store_settings =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'SystemProyect')
def leerArchivo():
basedatos={'prueba':{}}
for fname in os.listdir(path_to_store_settings):
    if fname == 'conexion.py':
        from SystemProyect.conexion import DATABASES
        basedatos=DATABASES
return basedatos
```

Y en el archivo conexion.py esta lo que me hace falta encriptar porque esta en texto plano

```
DATABASES={'prueba':{
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
'NAME': 'datos',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
'USER': 'sa',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
'PASSWORD': '00000',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
'HOST': '192.168.0.15',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
'PORT': '1433',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
'OPTIONS':{'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0'}
} }
```

Que podría hacer o me aconsejan algo.

Comment: No sé de qué forma encriptar te ayudaría, pues para desencriptarlo necesitas otra clave ¿dónde tendrías ésta? ¿En el código? ¿En otro archivo?

Comment: te sugiero usar esta herramienta: https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/